# Alertmanager email setting in kube-prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to make my Alertmanager can send an email while something break rules.
Since trying to make all set in Kubernetes, I tried kube-prometheus from this Github author (https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus).
I have already done the following steps:

```
kubectl create -f kube-prometheus/manifests/setup 
kubectl create -f kube-prometheus/manifests/
```

and basic functions of prometheus, alertmanager, and grafana are all set up.

Next, I am trying to make the alertmanager can send an email while something break rules, however most of references mentioned that modifying the smtp setting in "alertmanager.yaml" works perfectly, but I am confused about what .yaml in kube-prometheus should I modify to make the sending email function correctly?
Is there anyone having the experience on kube-prometheus (https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus), please share the comments with me. Appreciated!

Comment: Are you wanting to import your own custom alertmanager.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

In Prometheus Operator you configure you AlertManager config using a custom resource definition of type `AlertmanagerConfig`. ([example](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/example/user-guides/alerting/alertmanager-config-example.yaml)) Please note that the keys in the AlertManangerConfig are not always the same then in the native `alertmanager.yaml`.

I did not find a nice documentation, but here is the [definition or the CRD](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagerconfigs.yaml)